# How to get the index of a tapped object in a TableView?

Tags: ios, indexing, label, tableview

I got a tableView with custom cells. Inside each of these cells, there's a UILabel, which get it's text from an NSMutableArray. I set up a GestureRecognizer to see if this label is tapped or not. And if it's tapped, I go to another view.

Now in the method associated to the selector for the labels, I would like to get the index of the text in the NSMutableArray, corresponding to the tapped label. How could I do that?

Here is some sale code :
In the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, here's what I do :

```
    cell.Label.text = [tableLabelText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToViewControllerB:)];

    [cell.Label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.Label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
```

then I display everything...

and here's the goToViewControllerB method :

```
- (void) goToViewControllerB:(id)sender {
    if (!viewControllerB) {
    viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
}
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerB];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
}
```

If I do that, and if in my viewControllerB I modify something and go back to the Table View, then click on another label, I will be lead to the same viewControllerB, containing the previous modification. I do want to show a new viewControllerB for each label.

My idea was to get the index of tableLabelText corresponding to the tapped Label. The I could, whenever I call the goToViewControllerB:, create a new object of type ViewControllerB and insert it into a NSMUtableArray, at the same index...Something like

```
if ([ViewControllerArray objectAtIndex: "here the index i'm looking for"]){
"show it" }
else {
"create it and insert it into ViewControllerArray at the right index" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOfObject` method of array.

```
int index = [yourArray indexOfObject:tappedLabel.text];
```

Comment: @tvincent - Now instead of doing all these calculation why won't you keep it simple. You can directly use tableview delegate and check which particular row is tapped and then perform accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that the selection is disabled for a row...I only detect if a part of the customCell is tapped or not...

Answer (score 1):

For your UILabel, set its tag to be an integer (for example the row of the cell)
In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when you create the label use `label.tag = indexPath.row;`

Now in your gesture callback, get the tag from the view associated with the gesture recognizer object

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.textLabel.tag = indexPath.row.
```

and in your tapGesture method look for the gesture recognizer's view tag.

```
int indexFromArray = gesture.view.tag
```

And that is your index from the datasource array.
You can use this method even if you have the same text in more cells.